# How to create custom pagination in laravel 5.4 when getting data isn't coming in collection

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am trying to create pagination in laravel i made it successfully but in soe cases i m  failed i have the following method in my contoller of which i want to create pagination

Controller:

```
  public function city(city $job_city)
    {

        $data = privatejobcity::where('city_id', $job_city->id)->get();

        $private_job = [];
        foreach ($data as $values) {

            $private_job[] = private_jobadb::with('cities')->where('id', $values->private_jobabd_id)->paginate(5);
        }
$private_job = collect($private_job);


        return view('frontend.jobTestCatagory.jobsByCities', compact('data', 'private_job'));
    }
```

which give me results:

```
Collection {#347 ▼

      #items: array:13 [▼
        0 => LengthAwarePaginator {#355 ▶}
        1 => LengthAwarePaginator {#403 ▶}
        2 => LengthAwarePaginator {#423 ▶}
        3 => LengthAwarePaginator {#431 ▶}
        4 => LengthAwarePaginator {#453 ▶}
        5 => LengthAwarePaginator {#471 ▶}
        6 => LengthAwarePaginator {#491 ▶}
        7 => LengthAwarePaginator {#513 ▶}
        8 => LengthAwarePaginator {#535 ▶}
        9 => LengthAwarePaginator {#555 ▶}
        10 => LengthAwarePaginator {#575 ▶}
        11 => LengthAwarePaginator {#595 ▶}
        12 => LengthAwarePaginator {#615 ▶}
      ]
    }
```

and in my controller method if i remove this line `$private_job = collect($private_job);` shows the follwing results

```
array:13 [▼
  0 => LengthAwarePaginator {#355 ▶}
  1 => LengthAwarePaginator {#403 ▶}
  2 => LengthAwarePaginator {#423 ▶}
  3 => LengthAwarePaginator {#431 ▶}
  4 => LengthAwarePaginator {#453 ▶}
  5 => LengthAwarePaginator {#471 ▶}
  6 => LengthAwarePaginator {#491 ▶}
  7 => LengthAwarePaginator {#513 ▶}
  8 => LengthAwarePaginator {#535 ▶}
  9 => LengthAwarePaginator {#555 ▶}
  10 => LengthAwarePaginator {#575 ▶}
  11 => LengthAwarePaginator {#595 ▶}
  12 => LengthAwarePaginator {#615 ▶}
]
```

now when i use pagination helpers like `firstItem, count` throws an error that method not exist and some other errors depends on what I change in the code

Answer (score 0):

collect() is a helper method that references to Illuminate\Support\Collection class.

To work with paginations you need use a class that extends the Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator abstract class, like as Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator.

Illuminate\Support\Collection does not extends Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator. For this reason your pagination don't work.

To your case i recommend that you refactor your query and work with JOINS, like as:

```
$private_job = private_jobadb::leftJoin('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'private_jobadb.city_id')
->where('id', $job_city->id)
->paginate(5);
```

This will likely return a object of LengthAwarePaginator. With this your pagination will be work.

Before this, please verify the relationship and write the new query properly.